# F# error FS0039: The value or constructor 'input' is not defined

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

```
let getName name:string = 
    printfn  "the name is %s" name
```

All im trying to do is make the code display a string, but when I enter for instance "julian" i get the FS0039 erro but when I change it to (name:int) and enter a number it works perfectly fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let getName name:string =` means `getName` is a function returning a `string` and taking a parameter `name` with a type to be inferred - its temporary signature is `(name: 'a) -> string`. What is misleading is the whitespace: it's not because there is no whitespace here `name:string` that `:string` refers to the parameter `name` rather than the function `getName`.

Based on its body `printfn  "the name is %s" name` :

- The function should return `unit`
- The parameter `name` has type `string` (see `%s` placeholder)

So, you can :

- either add parentheses `let getName (name: string) = ...`
- or (better) drop the type annotation `let getName name =` to rely on the type inference that is working here due to `%s`.

One last point: your function is called "get something" but actually returns nothing. It's inconsistent and makes it harder to use and maintain. Something like `greet`, `print`, `printName` is more appropriate.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but once I tried both fixes for this and still ended up with the value is not defined error

Comment: @Julian you're not posting the whole code, are you?  Post the entire code that throws the error and the entire code that "works fine."

Comment: im using the interactive with only that bit of code highlighted

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing parens around `name:string`, because otherwise `: string` is parsed as the return value fo the whole function, and if your function just perform side-effects like printing, the return value is `unit`.

Comment: Sorry im new to coding in general and don't really understand what you mean. Thank you for the reply though

Comment: I mean, if `:string` is the type annotation of the `name` parameter, write it like this `(name: string)`. That will make it work.